# My front suspension keeps auto locking, brand new bike. Bike shops useless right now

Tags: suspension, lockout

I bought a Daymak Wildgoose electric fatbike bicycle. It has Forgo Zoom front suspension which I know is a lower end shock.

Since riding away from the store when I unlock the suspension and hit any bumps the suspension locks up and doesn't work. Even with the switch still in the unlocked position. For it to work again I have to move into the locked position and then back to unlocked. But as soon as I hit a tiny bump they lock straight away again.

I talked to the shop about it but given the times were going through right now they are near useless. If anyone has any ideas as to how i can fix this on my own please throw `em at me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you buy it direct from Daymak or from a retailer?

Comment: It was purchased through soar hobby. Licensed daymak retailer.

Comment: Considering how bad and heavy this suspension fork is I’d try to ask them to replace it with a rigid one.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest getting an assertion from the bike shop that this is warranty work, even if you can't get it there anytime soon.

You could also ask the shop to simply ship you a pre-tested replacement fork (and a star nut) and you get to swap them over, and then ship back the faulty one.

Ultimately the retailer will pass the warranty costs onto the wholesaler/manufacturer back up the supply chain.

---

Admittedly life's a bit off-base right now with C19 pandemic, but at least establish your case with both the reseller and the manufacturer.  Ultimately you as the consumer deserve a bike that works right.  It is brand-new!

So give them the chance to make it right, but also keep at it.

Comment: I tried emailing the company, they emailed once with a tiny bit of info then just stopped responding.  Its definitely covered under warranty the bikes brand new. Was just hoping that it was an easy fix and I could get it done myself.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't much else you can do without dismantling the fork entirely, to me it sounds like the lockout system in the fork wasn't assembled correctly in the first place.

Does it happen only when riding, or if you just compress the forks whilst not on the bike?  I can't find much info about a [Zoom Forgo](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/zoom-565-forgo-26-suspension-fork-681793) fork, but it doesn't seem to have a lockout setting, only preload and rebound adjustment. In terms of what you can do yourself, have you tried winding whatever adjustments the fork has all the way through their adjustment, from min to max a few times just to loosen anything up internally? Once you have done this, put both adjustments to around the middle of their travel and see if there is any change.

If this doesn't work, you could try leave the bike upside-down overnight, then right it again for a while before compressing anything. This will ensure whatever seals and shims make up the adjustment are lubricated, and then try the above test again.

Comment: Its brand new - disassembling the fork risks voiding the warranty.   If it were an old fork I'd agree, but perhaps not at this time.

Comment: @Criggie Thats why I didn't suggest stripping it down, just stated that its unlikely to be fixable without disassembly. Even on an old fork its likely to be something in the damper which isn't usually user serviceable.

Comment: At this point I have literally tried everything that I CAN do myself without dismantling the forks.

Comment: I have tried the upside down trick, my cousin suggested this. I tried going through the adjustments many times now. The fork is acting a little bit different now, it will compress a small amount if I push slowly. Quick and hard hits makes it lock instantly. I dont even get the chance to ride away before they lock. If I lock them, then unlock them they work great, but if I lift the front of the bike a little and drop it even a little bit hard they just lock instantly. Hit even the smallest bumps they just lock up. The store said I can bring it in, but it's my main transportation and they will

Comment: Keep it in QUARANTINE for several days before they even look at it right now. I just cant leave it. I would have to ride it over there (about a 20 minute ride)

Comment: @GregJames Unfortunately, that sounds like its broken. My only other idea is to check if there is some kind of grub screw on the lockout lever?

Comment: I'm thinking you're right thl33ter.

Comment: I just had a look, I dont see any screws anywhere on the fork. I've already had the lockout lever off too.

Comment: At this point I'm going to wait out the pandemic restrictions, and have the store look at it when it is over. I appreciate the messages everyone thank you very much